# Index automatically replaced when creating a new column out of it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently doing some exercises on a Pandas DataFrame indexed by date (DD/MM/YY). The current exercise requires me to groupby on Year to obtain average yearly values. 
So what I tried to do was to create a new column containing only the years extracted from the DataFrame's index. The code I wrote is:

```
data["year"] = [t.year for t in data.index]
data.groupby("year").mean()
```

but for some reason, the new column "year" ends up replacing the previous full-date indexing (which does not even become a "standard" column, it plain disappears), which came a bit by surprise. How can this be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include a sample of your dataframe in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a sample dataframe:

```
            value
2016-01-22      1
2014-02-02      2
2014-08-27      3
2016-01-23      4
2014-03-18      5
```

If you would like to keep your logic, you just need to call the column you want to take the `mean()` of and use `transform()` and then assign it back to the `value` column:

```
data['year'] = [t.year for t in data.index]
data['value'] = data.groupby('year')['value'].transform('mean')
```

Yields:

```
               value  year
2016-01-22  2.500000  2016
2014-02-02  3.333333  2014
2014-08-27  3.333333  2014
2016-01-23  2.500000  2016
2014-03-18  3.333333  2014
```